# Restrict attribute values in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to restrict a combination of attribute values in XML schema?
I have a tag with two attributes and I would like to permit some combinations of their values. E.g. if attribute_1 has value "A", then attribute_2 must not have value "B".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734733/xml-schema-restricting-the-value-type-of-an-attirbute-based-on-the-type-of-anot?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In XSD 1.1 you can use [assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions). Something like (untested):

```
<xs:element name="SomeType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="attribute_1" type="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="attribute_2" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:assert test="if (@attribute_1 = 'A') then @attribute_2 != 'B' else true()"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

See more examples [here](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html).